# NodeJS not able to process array of objects received via POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I'm having this collection of objects which are inside a html text area:

```
{"name":"John", "lname":"Doe","company":"example company","email":"johndoe@example.com"},{"name":"Katie","lname":"Jake","company":"example company","email":"katie@example.com"},
...
...
...
```

Is there a way to send the whole collection to node js and iterate through it to get values of objects?

My AJAX code:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://example.com/nodeapp",
    data: '['+document.getElementById("list").value+']',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

I tried to do a foreach on req.body, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var arr = req.body;

arr.foreach(element=>{
console.log(element.email);
})
```

Gives the error:

```
TypeError: arr.foreach is not a function
```

Comment: What do you see when you try to log req.body? Also, it's arr.forEach, not arr.foreach :) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: no it is not an array, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764822/req-body-cant-be-read-as-an-array

Comment: ``` [Object: null prototype] {  '[{"name":"John", "lname":"Doe","company":"example company","email":"johndoe@example.com"},{"name":"Katie","lname":"Jake","company":"example company","email":"katie@example.com"}]' : ' ' ``` @saglamcem This is what I see on console log of req.body

Comment: no it is not an array, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764822/req-body-cant-be-read-as-an-array

Comment: may be you ca try `E` caps `forEach`, but it is not an array, you have to use `in` loop or `of` loop

Comment: @DickensAS I tried E caps on forEach. Still the same result.

Comment: Then I confirm, it is not an array, use `in` loop or `of ` loop

Comment: try to parse string in textarea to object before sending to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem! Incase someone is stuck with the same thing, the whole thing was a string:

```
'[{"name":"John", "lname":"Doe","company":"example company","email":"johndoe@example.com"},
{"name":"Katie","lname":"Jake","company":"example company","email":"katie@example.com"},
...
...]'
```

Which was considered as one property in JSON which has no value while the server received it. Pretty much like this:

```
{
"<<the array in string format>>" : ""
}
```

How I fixed this was, I pushed the objects separately into a new array and sent it to server with JSON content type. (Which was an actual array of objects)

Answer (score 0):

At first , you have to parse the body by using JSON.parse() function .
Like this :

```
var arr = JSON.parse(req.body);

arr.forEach(element=>{
console.log(element.email);
});
```

The javascript's foreach also defined as arr.forEach(...) not arr.foreach(...) .